Examples of long running and consecutively numbered international meetings
I just saw a poster at the next office's door announcing the

95th Annual Meeting of the International Association of Applied Mathematics and Mechanics.

Here is another example of a meeting I will organize myself next year:

The 94th Séminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire

This brought me back to the following question that I was wondering about:
What are examples of long running and consecutively numbered international mathematics meetings?
Is there, for example, a (regularly and international) series that already passed its 100th instance?

https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ sounds more appropriate for this question.

Given that very many mathematicians frequently visit MO while much less do so for HSM, I'd prefer to keep it here for now.

The joint math meeting comes to mind. But like most other examples, it is numbered by calendar year, not by iteration. It seems that it exists since 1989, so pretty long but not close to 100 iterations.

It does seem like it would help to have something that meets more than once a year (such as the SLC, AAA, or PSSL already mentioned here), both because that means that using the year is ambiguous and because the number increases more quickly.

@ChristianStump "Many more people visit MO, so I should post here rather than in the appropriate site" does not seem a sound argument to me. You could use it to justify all sorts of spam and off-topic content.

Everyone is invited to ignore questions they are not interested in. But I consider it stupid to not allow fellow mathematicians to discuss their questions on MO, even if these might be slightly off-topic.

@ChristianStump: Strange to see the title of your seminar beginning in English and continuing in French.

@AlexM. I never realized, you are right. It is usually called SLC and the only practiced language is English now, while it was originally English, French, and German.

Slightly off-topic? There's more research mathematics in cooking recipes.

If MO wants to provide a welcoming environment for professional mathematicians, people should not try to exclude questions just because they can.

There’s the AAA (Arbeitstagung Allgemeine Algebra), Workshop on General Algebra, which has been running for over 50 years (since 1971). It takes place all around Central Europe several times a year, every year, and it’s currently up in AAA105 to be held in Prague (Czech Republic).

Awesome, this is probably the first I see a series number beyond 100!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Congress_of_Mathematicians.
Started in 1897, so long running.
As for the numbering:

In the aftermath of World War I, at the insistence of the Allied
Powers, the 1920 ICM in Strasbourg and the 1924 ICM in Toronto
excluded mathematicians from the countries formerly part of the
Central Powers. This resulted in a still unresolved controversy as to
whether to count the Strasbourg and Toronto congresses as true ICMs
... As a consequence of this controversy, from the 1932 Zürich
congress onward, the ICMs are not numbered.


The 109th Peripatetic Seminar on Sheaves and Logic (PSSL) will be in Leiden in two weeks' time.
https://dutchcats.github.io/PSSL-2024/
This series began in 1976 and meetings were for a long time held three times a year in various places in western Europe.  For more information, see
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Peripatetic+Seminar+on+Sheaves+and+Logic

British Mathematical Colloquium: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/BMC/

The British Mathematical Colloquium is the largest pure mathematical conference to be held annually in the UK. It has been held every year since 1949, usually around Easter, though some of the earlier meetings were in September.

The most recent one was the 75th: https://sites.google.com/view/bmc2024/home

OP asks for international meetings; I don't have a specific definition of the term, but the fact that this conference is called "British" suggests that it is limited to one country.

@FedericoPoloni At least today the participants and speakers of the meeting seem to be from all over the world. Doesn't that make it an international conference?

@testaccount Yes, that's also was I thought when looking at the website.
